# Dismiss activity shown with FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED

Tags: android, android-activity, lockscreen, dismiss

I'm showing an activity in lockscreen from a background service while the device is locked when the user is within a certain area (GPS obtained).

The activity has this code:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        getWindow().addFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
        ...
    }
```

And it is being called from the service like this:

```
    if (inArea){
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        if (pm.isScreenOn()==false){
            Intent wakeIntent = new Intent(mContext, mClass);
            wakeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            mContext.startActivity(wakeIntent);
        }
    }
```

When the user exits the area the activity should no longer be seen in lockscreen. But I cant get that.

I tried this when the user's GPS is outside the area:

```
    if (!inArea){
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

But the activity remains present in the lockscreen.

Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the service broadcast when the user exits the are.  Have the activity register a broadcast receiver for that broadcast.  If it receives that broadcast, have it finish() itself.

Or a dozen variations on this-  they all boil down to have the application get informed when its no longer in the area and kill itself.

Comment: Thanks Gabe. I tried your suggestion but it did not work. The broadcast is being received fine, and it calls the "finish()" method, but the activity is still shown when I wake the phone. Maybe the "finish()" should be called outside the "onReceive" of the BroadcastReceiver??? Thanks again for your help.     }
`BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("killLockScreen")){
     System.out.println("! KILL myLockScreen !");
     finish();
    }
   }
  };`

Comment: Got it! I'm calling both "finish()" and "onDestry()" methods when receiving the broadcast. Can this have a negative impact in any other way? (i.e. Battery drain, Memory leak, ...). Thanks again for your help Gabe.

Comment: Ondestroy shouldn't be called manually. The system will call that after a call to finish